# To override Container logs in Yarn using custom log4j

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, logstash, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to override YARN container log formatting using custom log4j.properties, but I am not able to do so.

I have tried to override `container-log4j.properties` in `hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar` and then replacing the jar, but with no effect.

I have also tried to place my own `container-log4j.properties` file in location `/etc/hadoop/conf` to make it override in classpath.

I am using HDP(Hortonworks) 2.2 distribution.
Basically I am trying to put socket appender in `container-log4j.properties` so as to analyze the container logs in `Logstash`.

Am I missing something or using wrong properties file or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

I did this for Hadoop 2.6. So this may be not applicable to your case.
And I realise that the question was unanswered for almost a year. But it still be useful to answer to those who will google the question (as I did)

Hadoop uses log4j. According to log4j documentation there is a system property log4j.debug which I find very useful (more: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig)

This property enables log4j initialization verbose output which enabled me to get better understanding where my mapper's log4j gets its configuration.

Also I used a pi calculator job as a small job to try override logging.

I launched

```
yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts='-Dlog4j.debug' 3 10000
```

and I've got

```
log4j: Trying to find [container-log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@deb6432.
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar!/container-log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar!/container-log4j.properties
log4j: Hierarchy threshold set to [ALL].
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[WARN,CLA, EventCounter].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category root set to WARN
log4j: Parsing appender named "CLA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "CLA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} %p [%t] %c: %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "CLA".
log4j: Setting property [containerLogDir] to [/hdfs/uuid/77fc1684-1751-4bf0-b474-5de75130dc23/yarn/logs/application_1467803702064_1954/container_e12_1467803702064_1954_01_000002].
log4j: Setting property [totalLogFileSize] to [0].
log4j: setFile called: /hdfs/uuid/77fc1684-1751-4bf0-b474-5de75130dc23/yarn/logs/application_1467803702064_1954/container_e12_1467803702064_1954_01_000002/syslog, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "CLA" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "EventCounter".
log4j: Parsed "EventCounter" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

So one can see that log4j takes a configuration from hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar

I extracted this file

```
jar xf hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar container-log4j.properties
```

modified it and put in my directory. The rest is just to figure out the way to put in somewhere before hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar in the classpath.

Unfortunately the job jar itself is the last one in the classpath. So it is impossible to override a config by putting your modified container-log4j.properties as a resource of your jar.

But fortunately a folder with a user cache is the first in the classpath. So
I added

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf=ERROR
```

to the config to get rid of all these warnings about using deprecated properties
and afterwards and relaunched a job using

```
arn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi -files ./container-log4j.properties -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts='-Dlog4j.debug' 3 10000
```

and voila! There is no warning from org.apache.hadoop.conf.

Enjoy